# Windows 8.1 Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.61030

Tags: c++, hadoop, windows-8

i'm trying to install hadoop on my Windows 8.1 but when i double click on the tar.gz file they propose me :
Windows 8.1 Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.61030
Modify Setup

Repair    Uninstall    Close

I did repair and uninstall/install but nothing change. It already happened to me and i went to the https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=30679
and dowload the files x64 and x86 but now it doesn't work

Comment: which tar.gz file did you download?

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html the 2.7 binary

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the message you get? The text of your question is poorly formatted.

Comment: Did you try extracting it with `7-zip`?

Comment: neither `hadoop-2.7.0-src.tar.gz` or `hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz` includes anything related to visual studio. So it looks like the program you installed to extract tar.gz files is not installed correctly. That is completely unrelated to hadoop. I would also recommend to use 7-zip.